# Nginx + PHP-FPM on Ubuntu giving "upstream sent invalid status" on uploading Joomla extension zip file

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a Ubuntu server running in an ESV VM emvironment and I've installed a webserver with this configuration:

- Nginx 1.0.5
- PHP 5.3.6 with PHP-FMP
- Mysql 5.1.62

I have an installation of latest version of joomla on this server and when I try to upload an install package (zip file containing joomla's extension files) I get "502 Bad Gateway" with the following error in nginx log file:

**2012/05/13 11:22:21 [error] 19911#0: *20 upstream sent invalid status "-1 Copy failed" while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.10.56.70, server: localhost, request: "POST /administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=install HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "radio.xx.xx", referrer: "http://radio.xx.xx/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer"**

I've searched all over the internet and I've changed too many parameters of php configuration, fpm config and nginx config including increasing execution times and etc but my problem still remains. I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with my Joomla and problem is in webserver but there's no usable log messages, except above message.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Quick and might be a stupid question, is php5-curl installed? :)

Comment: Yes, as I can see in phpinfo, curl 7.21.6 is installed.

Comment: Hmm, it's a tricky question. Nothing in the php-fpm error log? As I believe it's not enabled by default, you need to add `error_log = log/php-fpm.log` to your `/etc/php5/fpm/php5-fpm.conf` file. PHP might yield something... but, have you checked permissions/owner of the upload directory? If the permissions/owner is off, PHP won't be able to upload the file and save it out, which would make sense because of the "-1 Copy failed" error.

Comment: I have set all folders permission to 777 and owner groups for all of directories are my-default-user(radio):www-data.

Comment: I also did enable php-fpm error logging but all I have in the log file is fpm started and such data. nothing about this problem! php log also didn't give me any usable information! I really need to make it work! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of searching I found out that problem was because of `vsftpd` and the chmod that it was using for uploaded files. After uploading the files, PHP was not able to even read the files.

Instead of struggling with vsftpd I managed to upload my files with http and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2649066) may be of use to you.

I'm running into a similar problem with updating a single component. It seems to be related to permissions on files that it's trying to replace. That forum post suggests adding some extra info to the error messages it throws back so you can determine what files it's failing on.

Answer (score 0):

For me i uploaded the file over http i got something like:  1886#0: *37766 upstream sent invalid status "-1 Copy failed" while reading response header from upstream, client
In my nginx log, turned out that one of the directories did not exists "cli" in this case.